# TypeScript - static property creation optimization

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to JavaScript and since I come from strongly-typed languages I've chosen TypeScript.

I'd like to know what happens to variable `red` in `Red getter` in this code. Will it be recreated on every call (like in `Green getter`) or created once and used every time? Which is best?

```
class Color {
    public R: number;
    public G: number;
    public B: number;
    public A: number;

    static get Red(): Color {
        var red = new Color(255, 0, 0);
        Color.Red = function() { return red; }
        return red;
    }

    static get Green(): Color {
        return new Color(0, 255, 0);
    }

    constructor(red: number, green: number, blue: number, alpha: number = 255) {
        this.R = red;
        this.G = green;
        this.B = blue;
        this.A = alpha;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The other answers are totally right but I think there's a subtle issue they're not mentioning.  Because Red is defined as a getter it also gets an automatic empty setter that does nothing.  So when you call `Color.Red = function() { return red; }` you're passing that function into the setter for Color.Red, which does nothing, so that statement has no effect.  You can slap an `alert()` into the getter and call it a few times to see for yourself.

If you look at the generated JavaScript for this piece you'll see that the getter is created through [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), which is an interesting beast.  You could make your own call to Object.defineProperty to redefine the action of the getter, but that seems like a lot of work when `private static red : Color = new Color(255,0,0);` works perfectly fine.

As for which is best, it's a question of trade offs and what's more important to you.  Always returning a new Object is going to use up a lot more memory, but avoids the risk of somebody modifying Color.Green and causing a heck of a fun bug to track down.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get it cached you can do:

```
class Color {
    public R: number;
    public G: number;
    public B: number;
    public A: number;

    private static _red : Color = new Color(255,0,0);   
    static get Red(): Color {
        return _red;
    } 

    static get Green(): Color {
        return new Color(0, 255, 0);
    }

    constructor(red: number, green: number, blue: number, alpha: number = 255) {
        this.R = red;
        this.G = green;
        this.B = blue;
        this.A = alpha;
    }
}
```

This way the constructor is not called each time you use `Red`.

Answer (score 1):

Every time a getter is used, the function implementing it is invoked. The `Red` implementation isn't going to be accomplishing any sort of caching.